# How can I change the FeedItem's sender?

Tags: trigger, chatter, feeditem

In the case of the image, the user Alanna Clark updated an account and my trigger runned and posted the FeedItem.

But I want to change the sender ("Alanna Clark")  for another user called "INTERFACE" when the trigger runs. What do I have to do?

```
//Feed Post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.Body = 'Msg body';
post.ParentId = acc.Id ;
insert post;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [post](http://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099lMIAQ) you can try the below snippet

```
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = acc.Id ; 
post.createdById = '0057F0000088Oh8'; //Replace this id with Used id of INTERFACE
post.Body = 'Msg body';
insert post;
```